# Best way to create Spring beans

Tags: java, spring

I usually create Spring beans in two different ways:

Creating Services and Repositories manually:

```
public class Repository {
    ...
}

public class Service{

    private Repository repository;

    public Service(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Repository repository() {
        return new Repository();
    }

    public Service service() {
        return new Service(repository());
    }

    ...
}



@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    ...
}
```

Using spring annotations to autowire them:

```
@Repository
public class Repository{
    ...
}

@Service
public class Service{

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    ...
}

@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    ...
}
```

In the first approach you have full control of the bean creation, and in a future you could change Spring by another framework with minimum changes. On the other hand, the second way is much simple, especially when you have tons of beans in your application.

But I'd want to ask which of the two ways above would be better to create beans.

Thank you in advance

Comment: They are both equally good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will ever change off of spring. But if that is a major concern than do not use the autowire feature.

Either way make sure you have a comprehensive suite of unit tests which will guarantee, that if you change frameworks, that you can identify issues and bugs. Otherwise you will never feel comfortable changing frameworks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a matter of preference. We recently switched to using @Configuration since we needed different profiles for different situations. Both are good.